# Authentication mechanism for session management in java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications, spring-security, security

I am developing a web application using java-spring, where normal html files will post requests to a servlet using ajax. Here in this scenario what kind of authentication mechanism I can use for managing session so that it becomes secure? In fact before request goes to actual resource, I want to make sure the request is coming from a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure your AJAX URLs in exactly the same manner as normal ones (using `intercept-url` rules). Example to give you an idea:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <!-- Your normal URLs -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/product-list.html" access="ROLE_PRODUCT_VIEWER,ROLE_PRODUCT_MANAGER" /> 

    <!-- Your AJAX URLs -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajax/add-product" access="ROLE_PRODUCT_MANAGER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajax/view-product" access="ROLE_PRODUCT_VIEWER" />
    ....
</http>
```